# Why do I not get experience for quests?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Yesterday, the Warlords of Draenor Patch 6.0.2 released, and once you logged in the first time (with a level 90 character), a quest starts automatically and leads you to the blasted lands. All the quests from there do get you armor, but I don't get experience, theres not even an amount of experience displayed on the quest itself, is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you already at the level cap?

Comment: Level cap is still 90 till the expansion comes out (provided you have purchased it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, this is not a bug.

You are actually not playing the expansion itself yet, but its prepatch. Yes, general changes like the item squish, draenor itself and talent changes etc. are already patched in, but the level cap stays 90 until WoD releases (13th of November I think).
You currently do the pre-quests for Draenor, these probably intend to gear you up, make you ready for Draenor itself.

Comment: Unless Blizzard has a history of adding quest with no xp then changing them it's logical they won't add xp later unless the quests can be repeated after the expansion's release since it'll disadvantage anyone who did the quests with no exp before hand

Comment: I just can't remember how they've done it when MoP released

Comment: Pre-expansion launch events have, so far, always been removed from the game once the expansion proper goes live. So, it's intended that these quests give 0 XP since the level cap hasn't been raised yet, but once the cap is raised, these quests will be gone so there's no worrying necessary about depriving yourself of that XP by not waiting.

Comment: Are these quests available when someone isn't level 90? And if they are available do you get XP when I'm not level 90?

Comment: Not available before level 90.

Comment: It might be worth noting that a max level character **never** gains exp from quests, and any exp that would be awarded is converted into gold instead (unless the new WoD patch changed this).

Comment: These quests already have XP defined, but the XP is converted to gold since all players are currently at max level.

Answer (score -1):

Doing these quests before the expansion gets you a title instead.